# Visual C# Confused about DataGridView/Dataset details

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm after more direction and links to resources to learn rather than coding advice.

We are as a test project developing an application in Visual Studio 2013 in C# Winforms that is primarily data driven on a SQL Server 2012 database. It seems that data sources/datasets/tableadapters/datatables etc go a long way to making this easier, but as soon as you add even a little complexity it seems to get more difficult, and from my Googling everyone seems to achieve what they need in different ways.

For example, at the moment I am building a multistage form using a tab control that prompts the user for information which then gets added into a database. On the first form I can easily attach the datasource, and then grab and drag the form elements from "Details" as opposed to gridview. This generates the "toolbar" at the top that has options to browse through records, save etc. This works fine at a basic level, but when I want to do more with the data (for example I want to reference a column in a different table and outside of the dataset to populate a combobox with a list of options, which then form an insert I am having to manually write code to do this.

We're going to have to create hundreds of these forms, so I want to make sure the way I am doing this is correct. Therefore, my questions:

1) Is the way I am doing this the easiest way of selecting, creating and  manipulating the data?

2) Are there any GOOD resources on how to do Datasources right and then manipulate all the elements (books/tutorials etc).

3) Are there any resources on how to manipulate the datasets options (like the ability to save changes that are made without using the toolgrid control that gets generated).

I recognise I am out of my depth here and this question may seem fragmented, but I'm willing to learn, I just don't know "what" to learn. Any direction would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Seeing as you are using SQL Server 2012, is there any reason you aren't using entity framework instead? Datasets are fairly dated.

Comment: Winforms is also dated, you should use WPF instead

Comment: There is a reason I'm not using entity framework; I'd never even heard of it! I'm looking into it now, thank you both for your input I will look into WPF as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your question, this is rather a large subject. There will be a significant learning curve to some of the technologies I will mention. However, the upside will be more reliable, modern code that is easier to maintain.

These points have been listed in comments already, but I thought some more detail and direction might be helpful:

**ORMs (Object-relational Mapping)**

I try to avoid DataTables, DataSets like the plague because I hate to have to refer to cells with an index or a hardcoded string which then only returns an untyped object.

The more modern way is to have objects in your application that represent the database tables and map your typed data back to them.

- **Entity Framework**

  - Microsoft's offering, which I am not too fond of. I have had too many developer days lost on trying to get a specific entity regenerated on a different developer machine and also too many days lost dealing with releases due to poor handling of different schema names.
  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx
- **EntitySpaces**

  - This is a formerly commercial offering that is now open source. This is my current preferred ORM because it is fairly simple, but handles many of the pitfalls that other ORMs have. EntitySpaces also comes with its own entity generation software. The wiki entry gives a quick overview of supported databases and some basic query code you would write (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EntitySpaces).
  - http://entityspaces.net/www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx.html
  - http://download.cnet.com/EntitySpaces-Studio/3000-10250_4-10590953.html?tag=mncol;1
  - https://github.com/EntitySpaces/EntitySpaces-CompleteSource
- **NHibernate**

  - This is a fairly popular ORM choice that is open source and fairly powerful Configuration and initial setup is a very daunting task for new users. Also, nHibernate seems to require rolling your own functionality or finding an existing solution from somewhere else for much of what is included with EntitySpaces.
  - http://nhibernate.info/

Even if you go with WinForms in the end, I would highly recommend still using an ORM.

**WPF**

Windows Forms is pretty bad at drawing itself if you have to deal with multiple font/DPI settings, made worse by Windows Vista onward adding an additional font scaling type but still supporting the old XP style as well. Also, binding controls to data values in Windows Forms has always been right on the edge of terrible.

WPF was built around binding and it really removes a lot of the pain that happens in WinForms. You can also write a lot less code in many cases, if you are using WPF correctly. Unfortunately, to realize WPF's potential, you need to also learn the MVVM (Model View ViewModel) pattern. You are still free to write a WPF application in much the same way you would a WinForms application, but you are really missing out if you do it this way.

A couple important concepts to highlight are: **bindings** and **commands**. If you get those and a few others down then you will be well on your way with WPF and MVVM. Many developers use MVVM Light (https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) to remove some of the manual aspects of developing in MVVM, such as creating your ViewModel and basic commands.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial – This is a very quick guide that shows MVVM in WPF in a very simple program. You could branch out from here on subjects you want more clarification on.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

**Conclusion**

I think if you learn all there is to learn about those two subjects, you will be well on your way to writing any application you need. Unfortunately, I'm not sure which of the WPF/MVVM books are good so you may have to resort to trawling around the Internet. The same can be said for ORM knowledge, since there are many of them out there.

Comment: This was fantastic and exceptionally helpful. You've given me a lot to think about and research. Thanks for your help